# Struggling using SignalR in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, signalr

I have a Windows Phone 8 client.

I am using SignalR to communicate with my server.

I need my UI to update with messages from my server.

I know the server part is correct as I have set break points and have used a HTML5 client.

The issue is with WP8

I have never used WP8 before so I am not sure if I am doing it correctly.

I have this:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

          connection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                UpdateConnectionState("Not Connected");            
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateConnectionState(string.Format("Success! Connected with client connection id {0}", connection.ConnectionId));
                hubuserid = connection.ConnectionId;
                //not important for now LogIn();
            }
        });

        connection.Received += data =>
        {
            UpdateConnectionState(data);
        };
        connection.Error += ex =>
        {
            UpdateConnectionState(string.Format("An error occurred {0}", ex.Message));
        };
        connection.Closed += () =>
        {
            UpdateConnectionState(string.Format("Connection with client id {0} closed", connection.ConnectionId));
        };
        connection.Reconnected += () =>
        {
            UpdateConnectionState("The connection was re-established");
        };
    }
```

My UI initially states a connection has been made.

It is now receiving messages from the Server that I am stuck at.  I have also tried this:

```
  private async void UpdateTime(string data)
    {
        await dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            txtInfo.Text = data;
        });
    }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

        proxy.On<string>("internetUpTime", UpdateTime);

        connection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                UpdateConnectionState("Not Connected");            
            }
            else
            {
                UpdateConnectionState(string.Format("Success! Connected with client connection id {0}", connection.ConnectionId));
                hubuserid = connection.ConnectionId;
            }
        });

        //connection.Received += data =>
        //{
        //    UpdateConnectionState(data);
        //};
        connection.Error += ex =>
        {
            UpdateConnectionState(string.Format("An error occurred {0}", ex.Message));
        };
        connection.Closed += () =>
        {
            UpdateConnectionState(string.Format("Connection with client id {0} closed", connection.ConnectionId));
        };
        connection.Reconnected += () =>
        {
            UpdateConnectionState("The connection was re-established");
        };
    }
```

Which way is the correct way and what is wrong with my code?

thanks

Comment: So where is the issue exactly? What happens if you put breakpoints in WP8 code, does it break?

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to reply. That is just it. Whilst the connection is made I cannot seem to receive messages from my server. I know the server is sending a message to that hubid but the client us not receiving it. First, which code should I use? I have listed 2 ways from code I have found on the web. The breakpoint on the receive end us never hit

Comment: Has your code entered the continuation task after calling Start?

Comment: Hi, yes. Like I said the connection is made. The server receives the hubid ok as well

Comment: Alright, so where exactly is the error? `UpdateTime` doesn't get invoked?

Comment: hi, like I have previously said   :) there is no error. The event is not called. the 1st part of my question was to know if I had coded it right? Have I?  I suggested 2 ways of receiving a message from the server. Which is the correct one?

Comment: How does your server side look like? How are you calling events on the client?

Comment: Hi, the server side is fine i have other signalr clients (using JavaScript) that connect and receive like I previously said. It would REALLY help me if i knew what is the accepted way of receiving a message from a .NET client. This was part of my question. Do you know or not? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65196/discussion-between-toni-petrina-and-andrew-simpson).

Comment: Sorry for leaving abruptly. You should use `proxy.On<PckType>("broadcastMessage", msg => {});` to handle calls from the server.

Comment: That is OK.  I did not think you were being rude. Thanks for the clarification. I use to work a lot with Windows mobile 6.5 and I admit I have been left behind with Windows Phone. thanks

Comment: No problem. Please report back once you have it working. In case you still have issues, update the client code and post your server code for clarification. Just that one event.

Comment: I will do so. i need to remote login to my home PC.  My WP8 is connected to my dev PC. i am not sure if my phone needs to be 'awake' to run it though. It should be when i press F5. Lets find out..!

Comment: unfortunately I cannot test with my device as not detected :(. I am running W8 via my VM emulator.  I get an error when trying to run the WP8 emulator via VM Ware. I will have to report back later this evening but it looks logical so I am sure it will work..

Comment: @ToniPetrina Thank you very much. It works. It is so obvious when you showed me I almost feel embarrassed.  You should submit this as an answer I would happy to accept. Thank You

Comment: No problem. Glad it worked eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle calls from the server, use the following syntax:

```
proxy.On<PckType>("broadcastMessage", msg => {});
```

Where `PckType` is the type that is the equivalent to the type server sent with the following code:

```
Clients.Caller.broadcastMessage(pck);
```

SignalR acts as a RPC service which means methods called from the client must exist on the server and vice versa. Of course, this is only true for the `Hub` approach.

Comment: cheeky request but do you know how to run the wp8 emulators if i am running the ide from with vm ware?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I am using parallels and it works like a charm there.

Comment: Hi, that is OK :) like i said was being cheeky. But, in what context do you mean parallels?

Comment: I am using Parallels, a virtualization environment. But I presume you are on Windows 7 or somewhere where you don't have Windows 8 installed natively, right?

Comment: Hi, yes. VMware ware on w7 with a virtual w8 install

Comment: Have you tried this? http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Windows_Phone_8_SDK_on_a_Virtual_Machine_with_Working_Emulator

Comment: Hi yes thanks. That was what I followed. It works but signalr does not. Nor does it work running the  app via the device directly. At least not for me

Comment: Are you running signalr on localhost?

Comment: No, it points to my server hosted elsewhere. It initially connects then connection keeps dropping,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65444/discussion-between-toni-petrina-and-andrew-simpson).